# getting multiple versions of a global variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a global variable, and somehow I'm ending up with two versions of that variable. Can anyone see how this could happen?

My simplified scenario looks like this

```
a/
 init.py
 b/
   init.py
   file1.py
   file2.py
```

My first init.py has

```
from b.file1 import *
from b.file2 import *
```

In `file1.py` I have `__all__=[stuff, global_variable]` and following

```
global_variable = None
def doit():
  global global_variable
  global_variable = 1
  print("set global variable to %s" %(global_variable))
```

So finally when I do this:

```
import a
a.doit()
print(a.global_variable)
```

I see

```
set global variable to 1
None
```

Comment: `import *` makes a scope-local version (i.e. copy) of your module-global..

Comment: All "global" variables in Python are global to the module they're in.  `import *` creates a *new* global variable in the importing module, which is not linked in any way to the variable in the module it was imported from.

Comment: OK, that solves mystery, anyone knows where in Python docs this is documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package):

> Although certain modules are designed to export only names that follow certain patterns when you use import *, **it is still considered bad practise in production code**.
>
> Remember, there is nothing wrong with using from Package import specific_submodule! In fact, this is the recommended notation unless the importing module needs to use submodules with the same name from different packages.

Emphasis added.

The `from module import *` syntax is not recommended (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)). Try aliasing each module into its own concise namespace:

```
import b.file1 as f1
import b.file2 as f2
```